# CAN bus stuff error causes due to physical layer

Tags: can

I'm trying to diagnose the significant amount of bus "stuff errors" on my CAN network. Network is new and has not ran without these errors. Topology is as shown below.

[image]

- 18 Devices on CAN bus. 9 on each side, joined at din rail terminals.
- Cable on the outside of dotted lines are [this twisted pair
  cable](https://lappaustralia.com.au/downloads/LAPP/CAT2018_2019/LAPP-Main-Catalogue-2018-19%20_%2027-28.pdf).
- Cable on inside of dotted lines to din rail terminals is
  [this shielded twisted pair cable](https://lappaustralia.com.au/downloads/LAPP/CAT2018_2019/LAPP-Main-Catalogue-2018-19%20_%20363.pdf).
- Dotted lines represent deutsch connector.
- Bus length is roughly 20m - 25m
- Bit rate is 500kbits/s

My question relates to the physical layer because I can be fairly sure software is working correctly.

**Can any of the following things cause stuff errors on the bus?**

- Two different cable types
- Sections of non shielded cable
- A bad high or low connection to a device

Here is a picture of the CAN signals on a scope.

[image]

Here is an example of CAN traffic showing errors:

```
   355)      4916.3  Rx         0520  5  A6 0C 64 00 06 
   356)      4919.6  Rx         0523  8  05 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 
   357)      4919.8  Rx         0526  6  C0 01 08 00 08 01 
   358)      4920.3  Rx         0525  6  A8 73 AC 0D D0 02 
   359)      4920.5  Rx         0525  6  34 73 AC 0D D0 02 
   360)      4920.7  Rx         0523  8  B4 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 
   361)      4920.8  Error      0004  4  01 0A 01 00
   362)      4920.9  Error      0004  4  01 0A 02 00
   363)      4920.9  Error      0004  4  01 0A 03 00
   364)      4921.0  Error      0004  4  01 0A 04 00
   365)      4921.2  Error      0004  4  01 0A 05 00
   366)      4921.2  Error      0004  4  01 0A 06 00
   367)      4921.5  Rx         0523  8  10 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 
   368)      4921.7  Rx         0523  8  62 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 
   369)      4922.0  Rx         0523  8  1C 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 
   370)      4922.0  Error      0004  4  01 0A 04 00
   371)      4922.1  Error      0004  4  01 0A 05 00
   372)      4922.2  Error      0004  4  01 0A 06 00
   373)      4922.3  Error      0004  4  01 0A 07 00
   374)      4922.4  Error      0004  4  01 0A 08 00
   375)      4922.4  Error      0004  4  01 0A 09 00
   376)      4922.6  Error      0004  4  01 0A 0A 00
   377)      4922.6  Error      0004  4  01 0A 0B 00
   378)      4922.7  Error      0004  4  01 0A 0C 00
   379)      4922.8  Error      0004  4  01 0A 0D 00
   380)      4922.9  Error      0004  4  01 0A 0E 00
   381)      4923.0  Error      0004  4  01 0A 0F 00
   382)      4923.1  Error      0004  4  01 0A 10 00
   383)      4923.2  Error      0004  4  01 0A 11 00
   384)      4923.3  Error      0004  4  01 0A 12 00
   385)      4923.3  Error      0004  4  01 0A 13 00
   386)      4923.4  Error      0004  4  01 0A 14 00
   387)      4923.7  Rx         0523  8  9C 00 00 00 4F 00 00 00 
   388)      4923.7  Error      0004  4  01 0A 14 00
   389)      4923.8  Error      0004  4  01 0A 15 00
   390)      4924.1  Rx         0523  8  CC 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 
   391)      4924.1  Error      0004  4  01 0A 15 00
   392)      4924.2  Error      0004  4  01 0A 16 00
   393)      4924.3  Error      0004  4  01 0A 17 00
   394)      4924.4  Error      0004  4  01 0A 18 00
   395)      4924.4  Error      0004  4  01 0A 19 00
   396)      4924.6  Error      0004  4  01 0A 1A 00
   397)      4924.7  Error      0004  4  01 0A 1B 00
   398)      4924.8  Rx         0525  6  86 73 AC 0D D0 02 
   399)      4925.0  Rx         0525  6  28 73 AC 0D D0 02 
   400)      4925.1  Error      0004  4  01 0A 1A 00
   401)      4925.2  Error      0004  4  01 0A 1B 00
   402)      4925.4  Rx         0525  6  4B 73 AC 0D D0 02
```

Comment: Have you tried with one or two devices on the network, then start adding more and see when the error starts occurring?

Comment: @RonBeyer I have tried this but the results were very inconsistent and I wasn't able to narrow it down. For example, adding in the devices one by one lead to no errors on the bus but as soon as the network was reset, the errors came back.

Comment: And "PEAK" is an USB-to-CAN adapter connected to a PC via USB (e.g. *[PCAN-USB](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB.199.0.html)*)?

Comment: What detects the stuff errors? The USB-to-CAN adapter?

Comment: Those stuff errors should result in error frames (with at least 6 dominant bits). On the oscilloscope you can set the trigger on those by a positive pulse on CAN-H *longer* than 5.5 bit times (11 µs in this case). (Or a negative pulse on CAN-L. Even better would be on the differential signal (what the rest of the system actually uses).) This way you may be able to correlate the stuff errors to something - e.g. to a particular CAN device's messages or how late they occur in messages (only late instances *could* indicate CAN device oscillator accuracy problems). You could add your results here.

Comment: Re "this twisted pair cable": It says *"short-twisted conductor layers"*. I don't think that is the same as twisted pair (with an assured characteristic impedance). It doesn't look like anything even close to acceptable for this purpose (let alone the CAN standards). For starters, CAN-H and CAN-L would need to be on their own twisted pair.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only going to answer one of your questions. Can two different cable types cause errors. Yes, if the cables have different characteristic impedances, signals may be reflected at the cable interfaces. I have no idea whether that is an issue in your case, however.

Comment: Thanks, unforunately the datasheet does not show any impedance values for one of the cables so I can't be sure on the effect and replacing the cable is my last resort so exploring other options first.

Comment: Also, your schematic shows 120 ohm termination resistors. If your cable does not have 120 ohm characteristic impedance, there will be reflection at the ends as well.

Answer (score 1):

At room temperature, with 60 ohm total load between the two CAN wires, the differential voltage rapidly decay to ZERO.

Yet there are hundreds of milliVolts of difference,

Fix that.

Comment: are all the devices set to run on the same bit rate, same identifier lengths, etc?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf You're right. Fixed the differential voltage difference. Did not have signal ground connected because I didn't realize they were isolated transceivers.